# How kubelet - docker container communication happens?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I wondered about how kubelet communicates with docker containers. Where this configuration has defined? I searched a lot but didn't find anything informative. I am using https kube API server. I am able to create pods but containers are not getting spawned ? Any one knows what may be the cause ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: kubelet can also reach the  POD IP for httpGet probe, short explanation of how to troubleshoot this link would be helpful

Answer (score 4):

Kubelet talks to the docker daemon using the docker API over the docker socket. You can override this with `--docker-endpoint=` argument to the kubelet.

Pods may not be being spwaned for any number of reasons. Check the logs of your scheduler, controller-manager and kubelet.